# Change an input field before submit

Tags: jquery

I have to encode a domain name (IDNA) for a particular registrar using accents.

I have a simple input field :

```
<input type="text" id="idndomain" name="sld[0]" size="40" />
```

My jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#domainform').submit(function(){
        $.getJSON("includes/idna/idna.php", {
            domain: $("input#idndomain").val()
        }, function(data){
            $("div#result").html($('<b>' + data.encoded + '</b>'));
            $('#idndomain').val(data.encoded);
        });
        return true;
    });
});
```

So i'm sending a query to idna.php which encodes the domain name and returns a json array :

```
{"encoded":"xn--caf-dma.ch"}
```

Problem is that the form is being submited with the 'original' value, not the value returned by the json query.

Question is : how to 'wait' for json result first, replace the input field with the encoded string and them submit ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try binding to the submit button instead of the form, and explicitly invoke the form's `submit` handler within the json call's success callback:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#submitButton').click(function(){

                    // maybe disable the submit button once clicked?
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true); 
                    $.getJSON("includes/idna/idna.php", {
                            domain: $("input#idndomain").val()
                    }, function(data){
                            $("div#result").html($('<b>' + data.encoded + '</b>'));
                            $('#idndomain').val(data.encoded);
                            // now submit the form
                            $('#domainform').submit();
                    });
                    return false;
            });
    });
```

Comment: Be sure to allow for more than just a click, some people might submit a form with return or tab>space/tab>return.

Comment: why not bind with the $("selector").live("click", function(){}); ?
Always found it better just in case :)

Comment: I don't think there's enough context to recommend using `live`, it's really only needed if the submit button gets replaced (which I can't see happening based on the question)

Comment: Did not understand the 'live' thing, but the first answer just worked fine. Many thanks to all.